# Solving transport equation with pseudo-spectral and finite volume methods in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, transport-equation, finite-volume-method

I have a linear transport equation
$$ \dot{c}(x; t) + vc_x(x; t) = 0 \tag{1}$$
on an interval $[0; 2π]$ with $v = 1$, periodic boundary conditions and two different initial values
$$c(x; 0) = \sin(x)$$
and
$$
c(x,0) = \left\lbrace
\begin{aligned}
&0:x≤ \tfrac13; \\
&1: \tfrac13 < x < \tfrac23;\\
&0: x ≥ \tfrac23 ;
\end{aligned}\right.
$$

In both cases, we are to run until time $T = 4π$ when the solution should be identical again to the initial solution, because two full revolutions have been completed. I wish to solve this using matlab so I can get the "animated" graph as result (read further). I want to use "Heaviside" to specify the second initial value in an elegant way.

I am lost but what I know so far is that to advance this Equation $(1)$, is in essence a wave equation. So whatever initial conditions you put in, they should translate in the x-direction as time passes. From my very basic knowledge, I understand that making an array to hold the "old" values of $c(x,t)$, and another one to hold the arrays of new values $c(x,t+\Delta t)$. Resolution selected in $x$ by calling $\Delta x=2\pi/N_x$, and with some timestep $\Delta t$. Set initial conditions as $c(x,t=0)$ and as above which is then iteratively advances the given eq 1 until the time equals $4π$.

*Now I specifically want to use pseudo-spectral method with implicit midpoint rule whose code I already have available to me and first order upwind Finite Volume method with forward Euler for the transport equation*

```
Advance the equation in time by making a for-loop, and stepping the solution forward.
For example equation is df(x,t)/dt = v*f(x,t), then we can write
for k=1,nx !nx=number of points in x direction f(k,0)=whatever your initial conditions are endfor
dt=1.d-3 !dt is some arbitrary time step
for n=1,ntimes for k=1,nx f(k,n)=f(k,n-1)+vdtf(k,n-1) endfor!
now then replace the old values with the new ones for k=1,nx f(k,n+1)=f(k,n) endfor endfor
```

everything can be made much easier by exploiting that Matlab can update entire arrays, but I forget the exact syntax. I am a matlab beginner so please do this for me and return a single package of code that I can directly run with the resultant figures.

Comment: Accepted. Sorry, I am new to SE and didn't know about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The upwind scheme for the linear advection equation $c_t + v c_x = 0$ writes
$$
c_i^{n+1} = c_i^n - \frac{\Delta t}{\Delta x} \left( v^+ (c_i^n - c_{i-1}^n) + v^- (c_{i+1}^n - c_i^n)\right) ,
$$
using the notations $c_i^n \simeq c(i\Delta x, n\Delta t)$, and $v^+ = \max\lbrace v, 0\rbrace$, $v^- = \min\lbrace v, 0\rbrace$. It is stable under the Courant-Friedrichs-Lewy (CFL) condition $\gamma < 1$, where $\gamma = |v|\frac{\Delta t}{\Delta x}$ is the Courant number.

Here is a Matlab code for the upwind scheme with the sinusoidal initial data (the rest can be adapted as desired):

```
% physical parameter
v = 1;

% numerical parameters
Nx = 100;       % number of points
CFL = 0.95;     % Courant number
T = 4*pi;

% additional variables
vp = max(v,0);
vm = min(v,0);
dx = 2*pi/Nx;
dt = CFL*dx/abs(v);

% data initialization
x = linspace(0-dx,2*pi+dx,Nx+3);
t = 0;
c = sin(x);
c(1) = c(Nx+2);
c(Nx+3) = c(2);
ctemp = c;

% graph
figure(1);
clf;
h = plot(x,c);
xlim([0 2*pi]);
ylim([-1 1]);

while t<T
    % upwind integration
    for i=2:Nx+2
        ctemp(i) = c(i) - dt/dx*( vp*(c(i)-c(i-1)) + vm*(c(i+1)-c(i)) );
    end

    % boundary conditions
    ctemp(1)    = ctemp(Nx+2);
    ctemp(Nx+3) = ctemp(2);

    % actualization
    c = ctemp;
    t = t + dt;
    set(h,'YData',c);
    drawnow;
end
```

Here is the output:

[image: Output]

A convenient way of replacing the sinusoidal data by the rectangular data is to write `c = (1/3<x).*(x<2/3)` instead of `c = sin(x)` in line 18 of the previous piece of code.

The pseudo-spectral method writes
$$
\hat{c}^{n+1}(\xi) = R(\xi)\, \hat{c}^{n}(\xi) \, ,
$$
where the $\hat{\cdot}$ denotes the (time-dependent) Fourier transform in space with spatial frequency $\xi$, and
$$
R(\xi) = \frac{1}{1+\text{i}v\xi\Delta t}\,
,\qquad
R(\xi) = \frac{1-\text{i}v\xi\Delta t/2}{1+\text{i}v\xi\Delta t/2}
$$
correspond respectively to the right rule (implicit Euler time integration) and to the trapezoidal rule. To use this method in its right rule version, the previous piece of code is adapted as follows:

- the lines of code 19-20, 36-38 which account for the periodic boundary conditions should be removed.
- here, `Nx = 2^nextpow2(100)` is a power of two, `x = (0:Nx-1)*dx`, and `xi = [0:Nx/2-1 0 -Nx/2+1:-1]`
- the loop in time is replaced by

  ```
  while t<T
      % Fourier transform
      ctemp = fft(c,Nx);

      % actualization
      R = 1./(1 + 1i*v*xi*dt);
      c = real( ifft(R.*ctemp,Nx) );
      t = t + dt;
      set(h,'YData',c);
      drawnow;
  end
  ```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is so concise and clearly what I wanted.

To adopt the FVM code, I know that the boundary condition needs to be fixed to make it periodic. This requires changes only in a single line where u_left is set. but what other parameters do I need to modify before the loop?

Can you also please modify the same work for pseudo-spectral with implicit midpoint (my code attached to post)

It will be great help if you can modify both of them and let me know where. Thank you so much Harry, you have been immensely helpful!

Comment: Can you Generate one set of figures showing the global error with matlab's norm around xj (FVM) or at the node xj (pseudo-spectral method) and between Nx = 100 and Nx = 1000 mesh points/cells in simulations and with the number of time steps for each simulation to Nt = 2.4xNx.
Then, can you produce a second set that show the same error versus runtime, measured using Matlab's tic and toc commands for both numerical methods and both initial values.

Then we can conclude that the FINITE VOLUME METHOD with upwind is better because no gibbs oscillations yes?