# Python Lax-Friedrichs and central scheme programming

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, python

Good day :)

I found this exercise:

Consider $q_t + aq_x = 0$ with a constant velocity $a$.

Write a computer program that implements this equation using both the central scheme and also the Lax-Friedrichs scheme.

Use periodic boundary conditions. The initial data is a box followed by a Gaussian. Check the instabiliy of the central scheme for varaious CFL numbers. Check the dissipation of the Lax-Friedrichs scheme for large times.

Tryed to do it with Python and this is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 100
t_min = 0
t_max = 1
k = (t_max-t_min)/N
x_min = 0
x_max = 1
a = 1
h = (x_max-x_min)/N
alpha = a*k/(2*h)
x = np.arange(x_min, x_max+2*h, h)
u_0 = np.exp(-225*(x-0.3)**2)
u_0[np.where((x>=0.6) & (x <= 0.8))] = 1.0
u_lf = u_0.copy()
u_cs = u_0.copy()
u_num1 = u_0.copy()
u_num2 = u_0.copy()
t = 10000

plt.clf()

for j in range(N):
    u_num1[j] = (u_lf[j+1]+u_lf[j-1])/2 - alpha*(u_lf[j+1]-u_lf[j-1])
    u_num2[j] = u_cs[j] - alpha*(u_cs[j+1]-u_cs[j-1])
u_lf = u_num1.copy()
u_cs = u_num2.copy()

u_ex = np.exp(-225*(x-0.3-(a*t)%t)**2)
u_ex[np.where((x>=0.6) & (x <= 0.8))] = 1.0

u_ex=u_ex%len(u_ex)
u_lf=u_lf%len(u_lf)
u_cs=u_cs%len(u_cs)

plt.plot(x, u_ex, 'r-', label="Exact solution", fillstyle='none')
plt.plot(x, u_lf, 'o', label="Lax-Friedrichs", fillstyle='none')
plt.plot(x, u_cs, '^', label="Central scheme", fillstyle='none')
plt.axis((0, 1, -.5, 1.5))
plt.legend(loc='lower right')
plt.suptitle("t = %1d" % (t))

plt.show()
```

I think there are some errors which I don't see, since the central scheme is perfectly stable and the LF scheme is not dissipating for any time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the above choice of parameters, we have $a k/h = 1$, which is a very particular case for which some numerical schemes provide the exact solution. This property is sometimes called the *unit CFL condition*, see Exercise 4.2 p. 85 of the monograph by LeVeque (2002). Besides this feature, OP uses the same number of points $N$ both in space and time (there is no reason to do so in practice). Moreover, OP forgot to implement the periodic boundary conditions $$
\begin{aligned}
Q_{0}^{n} &= Q_{N-1}^{n} \\
Q_{N}^{n} &= Q_{1}^{n}
\end{aligned}
$$
see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2592402/418542) for instance, and other related posts on this site.

Comment: could you help with those periodic boundaries?

Comment: @jigga answer updated